# how to hide the qtip

Tags: jquery

Hi i am using Qtip in my Project, i need a little bit help in it, i have placed a condition which the checkbox boolean is true, qtip is active, now what i want is this i want to hide the qtip when checkbox boolean is false, how i am able to do that, anyhelp will be awesome. Thnxs in advance!

Answer (score 7):

QTip has a "hide" method that should work.

For example, if I setup a QTip like this:

```
$(".some-selector").qtip({content:"Hello, World!", hide: {delay:10000}});
```

Normally, this wouldn't hide until 10 seconds after I move the mouse away. But if I want to immediately hide it, I can do this:

```
$(".some-selector").qtip("hide");
```

Comment: Adam i have implemented your 2nd way, because i dont want any delay in it, but the code is not working, i have written this code to hide it, if(checkbox.checked==false)
          {
                $("#selector").qtip("hide");
          }

Comment: Yeah, the 2nd line of code is really all you needed.  The first line was just an example of setting up a qtip.

Comment: but its not working...2nd one..i have written the code as you can see..is there any problem in the code line?  if(checkbox.checked==false) { $("#selector").qtip("hide"); }

Comment: Are you sure that "checkbox.checked==false" is working correctly? Try something like: if ($("#checkbox_selector").is(":checked") == false)) { $("#selector").qtip("hide") }